# How do I install/use the phpize command?

Tags: php, sqlite, command, wampserver

I am intending to use SQLite 3 with PHP 5. I found this: http://packages.debian.org/etch/web/php5-sqlite3 but I am having problems with installation:

1. unzip & untar the package
2. run "phpize"
3. run "./configure --with-sqlite3=/path/to/your/sqlite3/install
4. make && make install
5. (optionally) copy DB/sqlite3.php to /path/to/php/lib/php/DB/sqlite3.php

I understand that phpize is a command used in cmd. But in which folder should I run this command? It seems that I don't have this command installed yet. How do I install this? I'm on Windows, and is using Wampserver for PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you've got don't typically make sense for Windows, unless you're running GNU Make.

You ought to have a look at this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php